# IO delay causes 2 iterations in for loop in JAVA

Tags: java, for-loop

I was testing some piece of code and came across something interesting on which I would need some expert opinion.

A simple program that stops the loop when the input is `s` but seems the on each input the loop is iterated twice, i guess that's because of the IO delay. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        int i;
        System.out.println("Type s to stop.");
        for(i = 0; ; i++) {
            char value = (char) System.in.read();
            if(value=='s'){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Pass # " + i);
        }
    }
```

**output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter a char `a` as an input, there are actually two characters which are entered.

- `a`
- `\n`

But, when you are reading a `char`, it reads one by one. Hence, it is looped twice.

Comment: Any explanation why it might even loop 3 times?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I can't reproduce your problem with iterating 3 times on Windows. Are you using linux? That might append `\r\n` after you type a char. Which explains the 3 times looping i guess

Comment: It would loop the length of the `chars` entered +1. If you enter `ab`, it would loop 3 times.

Comment: ab are 2 characters. @PankajSinghal

Comment: Yes. That's what I said, IF you enter `ab`, it would loop 3 times for `a`, `b`, `\n` respectively. A situation which @XtremeBaumer might be encountering.

Comment: I'm on windows and the characters it gets for input `1` are `49`,`13`,`10`. Looks like I get `\r\n` on windows as well

Comment: `13` is `\r` & `10` is `\n`. So, `a\r\n` is what's actually being entered

Comment: So maybe only print when `!Character.isWhitespace(value)`

Comment: @Lino Windows is the OS that uses \r\n by default, Linux uses \n only

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt then I got mixed something up. I use windows but have never encountered `\r\n`